# Sed regex change of file

Tags: regex, sed

I am (unsuccessfully) trying to substitute the database host entry in a Magento local.xml file (the connection string file).

The line is the following:

```
<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
```

I want to find the line that contains "host" with sed and then replace the content of the inner brackets with something else.

Note - the content of the inner brackets won't always be "localhost", so s/localhost/lala/g won't work.

I got to the following:

```
sed -i "/\<host\>/s/.../lala/2" local.xml
```

Help please.

Comment: `<` and `>` are not special `regex` characters, there is no need to quote them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's|\(<host><!\[CDATA\[\).*\(\]\]></host>\)|\1lala\2|' file
```

or

```
sed -E 's|(<host><!\[CDATA\[).*(\]\]></host>)|\1lala\2|' file
```

Output:

```
<host><![CDATA[lala]]></host>
```

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot. Switched to "sed -i" and it was replacing them perfectly. Thanks a lot for the lesson and info.